# not returning data of node

Tags: java, linked-list

can somebody tell me why it's not giving the value of toRemove?? I'm trying to remove the last element from a linked list.

```java
public E removeLast() throws Exception {
    MyNode<E> temp = head;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("CANNOT REMOVE FROM EMPTY LIST");
    } else {
        while (temp.next.next != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        MyNode<E> toRemove = temp.next;
        temp.next = null;
    }
    return toRemove.data;
}

static class MyNode<E> {
    E data;
    MyNode<E> next;

    MyNode(E data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Compiler errors are there for a reason. Read them carefully and you might understand what it means. And if you don't understand, then that's fine, but please edit it into the question so that others can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you declared the `toRemove` variable inside the else scope, so you cannot access it outside the if/else.

Comment: An easy fix in this case is to just move the `return` inside the `else` block.